# Unit test cases when its mobile should not render links

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, reactjs, redux

- my gist entire code here https://gist.github.com/js08/47c56dff0e4b75a281ae
- I have an application where it shows different templates for desktop and mobile on basis of build environment.
- I am successfully able to develop it where I need to hide the navigation menu for my mobile template.
- right now I am able to write one test case where it fetches all the values through the prototypes and renders them correctly
- but I'm not sure how to write the unit test cases, because when its mobile it should not render nav component.

Providing code below(test case):

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import {SportsTopPortion} from '../../../src/components/sports-top-portion/sports-top-portion.jsx';
require('../../test-utils/dom');


describe('"sports-top-portion" Unit Tests', function() {
    let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();

    let sportsContentContainerLayout ='mobile';
    let sportsContentContainerProfile = {'exists': 'hasSidebar'};
    let sportsContentContainerAuthExchange = {hasValidAccessToken: true};
    let sportsContentContainerHasValidAccessToken ='test'; 

    it('should render correctly', () => {
        shallowRenderer.render(<SportsTopPortion sportsWholeFramework={sportsContentContainerLayout} sportsPlayers={sportsContentContainerProfile} sportsAuthentication={sportsContentContainerAuthExchange} sportsUpperBar={{activeSportsLink:'test'}} />);
        //shallowRenderer.render(<SportsTopPortion sportsWholeFramework={sportsContentContainerLayout} sportsPlayers={sportsContentContainerProfile} hasValidAccessToken={sportsContentContainerHasValidAccessToken}  />);

        let renderedElement = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
        console.log("renderedElement------->" + JSON.stringify(renderedElement));

        expect(renderedElement).to.exist;
    });



});
```

Code snippet where test case need to be written:

```
if (sports.build === 'mobile') {
    sportsNavigationComponent = <div />;
    sportsSideMEnu = <div />;
    searchComponent = <div />;
    sportsPlayersWidget = <div />;
}
```

Comment: Maybe better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @markerikson but still I didnt complete my test cases yet